# Recorrer array de imagenes Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-7

Buenas estoy recorriendo un array de imagenes pero en la vista no me las muestra, no se si me falta algo en mi vista.
En el controlador recibo todos los parametros de mi form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la vista:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($property['images'] as $image)
        <div class="col-3 m-2">
            <img src="{{ asset('images') }}/{{ $image->name }}"></img>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Pero me sale asi:

[image: imagen vista]

Comment: como returnas tus imagenes a la vista?

Comment: lo que pasa es que no las guardo simplemente genero una vista previa partiendo del formulario

Comment: Haz intentado mostrar una vista previa con js?

Comment: asi lo realizo, pero no muestra las imagenes porque no estan guardadas en la bd, y no se como mostrarlas

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo JS?

Comment: function showPreview(){
    
    form = document.getElementById('property_form_create');
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.action = '{{ url('properties/preview')}}';
    form.method = "post";
}